# C - Infinite for loop

Tags: c

The `for` loop in this code never finishes and is stuck in an infinite loop but I can't figure out why. I've tried using a temp variable in place of `i` when doing the assignment within the `for` loop but that didn't work either.

The pointer is pointing to an array of size `10` and the rest of the code runs fine without the `for` loop being in there. Also the computer only guesses `0`. I'm guessing this is just a dumb mistake on my part but I can't figure it out.

edit: just pull all the code in post

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void setBoard(int *board);
void setComputerBoard(int *board);
int playGame(int *human, int *computer);

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int humanBoard[10];
    int *human = humanBoard;

    int computerBoard[10];
    int *computer = computerBoard;

    setBoard(human);
    setComputerBoard(computer);

    int winner = playGame(human, computer);

    if (winner == 0)
        printf("Computer Wins!\n");
    else
        printf("Human Wins!\n");

    return 0;
}

void setBoard(int *board) {
    int pos1, pos2, i;
    printf("Enter 1st position: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos1);

    while (pos1 > 9 || pos1 < 0) {
        printf("Enter 1st position: ");
        scanf("%d", &pos1);
    }

    printf("Enter 2nd position: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos2);

    while ((pos2 > 9) || (pos2 < 0) || (abs(pos2 - pos1) != 1)) {
        printf("Enter 2nd position: ");
        scanf("%d", &pos2);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", i);
        *(board + i) = 0;
    }

    *(board + pos1) = 2;
    *(board + pos2) = 2;
}

void setComputerBoard(int *board) {
    int pos1 = rand() % 10, pos2;
    if (pos1 == 9)
        pos2 = pos1 - 1;
    else
        pos2 = pos1 + 1;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i != pos1 && i != pos2)
            *(board + i) = 0;
        else
            *(board + i) = 2;;
    }
}

int playGame(int *human, int *computer) {
    int winner = -1;
    int computerShot, humanShot;
    int computerHit = 0, humanHit = 0;
    int i;

    while (winner == -1) {
        computerShot = humanShot = -1;

        printf("Computer guesses ");
        do {
            computerShot = rand() % 10;
        } while ((*(human + computerShot) != 1) && (*(human + computerShot) != 3));

        printf("%d\n", computerShot);
        if (*(human + computerShot) == 2) {
            printf("HIT!\n");
            *(human + computerShot) = 3;
            computerHit++;
        } else {
            printf("MISS!\n");
            *(human + computerShot) = 1;
        }
        printf("Human Board: \n");
        printf("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (*(human + i) == 0)
                printf("* ");
            else
            if (*(human + i) == 1)
                printf("M ");
            else
            if (*(human + i) == 2)
                printf("S ");
            else
                printf("H ");
        }

        printf("\nComputer Board: \n");
        printf("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (*(computer + i) == 0)
                printf("* ");
            else
            if (*(computer + i) == 1)
                printf("M ");
            else
            if (*(computer + i) == 2)
                printf("S ");
            else
                printf("H ");
        }

        printf("\nEnter guess: ");
        scanf("%d", &humanShot);
        printf("You guessed %d\n", humanShot);
        if (*(computer + humanShot) == 2) {
            printf("HIT!\n");
            *(computer + humanShot) == 3;
            humanHit++;
        } else {
            printf("MISS!\n");
            *(computer + humanShot) == 1;
        }

        printf("Human Board: \n");
        printf("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (*(human + i) == 0)
                printf("* ");
            else
            if (*(human + i) == 1)
                printf("M ");
            else
            if (*(human + i) == 2)
                printf("S ");
            else
                printf("H ");
        }
        printf("\n");

        printf("Computer Board: \n");
        printf("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (*(computer + i) == 0)
                printf("* ");
            else
            if (*(computer + i) == 1)
                printf("M ");
            else
            if (*(computer + i) == 2)
                printf("S ");
            else
                printf("H ");
        }
        printf("\n");
        if (computerHit == 2)
            winner = 0;
        else
        if (humanHit == 2)
            winner = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: which loop? What is your input? Show MCVE.

Comment: Memory overwrite maybe, if the caller of setBoard has the data pointed to by board on the stack?

Comment: As an aside: Take a look at the `do {} while(condition);`-loop. Also, check the return-value of `scanf`!

Comment: Fyi, turn on your compiler warnings to pedantic levels. Eg: `*(computer+humanShot) == 3;` is *not* an assignment, neither is `*(computer+humanShot) == 1;` Also, unrelated to your immediate problem, your `playGame` function never actually returns the `winner` value, so anything calling it is being lied to when they think they're getting anything besides *undefined behavior* for a response.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not the for loop, but the do-while loop in the playGame function. The while condition needs to be changed to

```
while ((*(human+computerShot == 1) || (*(human+computerShot) == 3));
```

because you want to redo the shot when it DOES equal 1 or 3 (already hit or miss respectively)

Comment: If I change it to while ((*(human+computerShot == 1) || (*(human+computerShot) == 3)); then the code is stuck in an infinite loop there

Comment: odd, i just ran it fine. I'll take a closer look just in case I'm not running your code verbatim.

Comment: @Bruailen note that the line printf("%d", i) won't print until its flush with a manual call to flush or by printing a newline character. Anyway, I just copied your code verbatim and only changed the line that I mentioned above and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the do{} while(); loop and it runs fine now. I have no idea why it gets stuck in it no matter what I try. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

At some point in the loop, the value of i is changed to zero by the pointer. Your code is also assigning pos1 and pos2 to zero.